# How to add button end of uitableview with swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to add button or row end of uitableview. I used tableview footer but its not solution for me. I also tried others way but ı didnt found any result. How can ı pass this problem.

Thanks..

Comment: U can take a cell for it and return your count + 1.Then you have to check for last index and load that cell

Comment: You want the button to stay always at the bottom of screen or you want to scrool it with the tableView ?

Comment: Why footer didn't work? do you want to keep at the end of the tableview even if you have no cells in it? i.e keep it at the bottom even if the content size of the table view is less than its frame?

Comment: I list 20 person tableView. end of list staying bottom of page.when ı scrool view and ı see enf of list. I want to add button end of list its stay always there. its task is load more person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use UIViewController instead of UITableViewController:

- In storyboard add UITableView to your view controller
- Create an IBOutlet for UITableView - connect it
- Conform your view controller to UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource
- set tableView.delegate = self and tableView.dataSource = self
- In storyboard add a button bellow table view and set top button's constraint to be few (e.g. 4) points away from table view's bottom constraint
- Create IBOutlet for button and connect it
- Add height constraint for your button - set it to **0.0**
- Set button's title to empty string ("")
- Create IBOutlet for button's height constraint and connect it
- Check when your table view reaches the end - to check whether your table reached the bottom you can implement `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` and check if indexPath.row is the last item in your data source (there are other ways too so you are free to check them)
- When your table reached the end - simply set button's title to your desired title with `button.setTitle(for)` and animate button's constraint to another height (big enough to see the whole button)
- When button is pressed you can just do the opposite animation: set button's title to "" and animate height constraint change back to 0.0